# Should I set Diffie-Hellman parameters for nginx SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have set up nginx with SSL. Everything works perfectly, with online tools giving the domain a good score.

Now I am wondering about one particular nginx configuration option; [ssl_dhparam](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#ssl_dhparam). Should I generate and set these parameters? Does it have any influence on security or computational load of SSL?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I generate and set these parameters?

Yes.

> Does it have any influence on [the] security...of ssl?

Yes, when enabling [Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Forward_Secrecy). An [appropriate](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Backward_Compatible_Ciphersuite) [ciphersuite](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Non-Backward_Compatible_Ciphersuite) must also be configured.

If a future attacker compromises your TLS, with [PFS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Forward_Secrecy) past traffic they intercepted and retained still cannot be decrypted.

[Generate a DHE prime](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#DHE_handshake_and_dhparam) **no smaller** than your SSL certificate RSA private key. Given a 2048 bit private key:

```
$ openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
..+..+...............+
```

> Does it have any influence on [the]...computational load of ssl?

Too little to worry about.

- conventional wisdom that TLS is slow is outdated
- the advantage of [PFS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Forward_Secrecy) outweighs the cost
- TLS [is well handled by modern CPUs](https://istlsfastyet.com/#cpu-latency); adding DH has a minor incremental cost compared to the total cost of TLS
- this cost is only incurred during the TLS handshake; a well-tuned TLS does the handshake infrequently or otherwise reduces the cost with [session resumption](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch04.html#TLS_RESUME), [false-start](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch04.html#TLS_FALSE_START), [OCSP stapling](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch04.html#_ocsp_stapling), and [more](https://istlsfastyet.com/#cpu-latency)

Google I/O 2014 had a good [HTTPS Everwhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBhZ6S0PFCY) talk which covered these and related topics in a broad fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Diffie helman is a good algorithm for key exchange but it takes too much time for computation slowing your website down. I recommend using `RC4-SHA` which is weaker than DH but serve its purpose. If it helps, google.com uses `RC4-SHA`. You can check out the algorithm for any website using the following:

```
openssl s_client -host HOSTNAME -port 443
```

I suggest you check out what kind of key exchange and encryption other websites similar to yours are using and use a suitable algorithm. 
Also read out [this](http://matt.io/technobabble/hivemind_devops_alert:_nginx_does_not_suck_at_ssl/ur) article on the same topic.

Comment: Perpetuating weaker security because of perceived costs is outdated and bad advice.

Comment: This was bad advice from the start, and it's now factually incorrect. Running `openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443` today gives:
`Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: AES128-SHA`